# How to root VIVO V3 and install custom ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, root-access, recovery-mode, custom-roms

I want to root my vivo v3 mobile to use it better.

Also want to install recovery like CWM/TWRP.
After that custom ROM like cyanogenmod or any other because it's current UI sucks.

I tried with some apps but that are not effective.

Please give me all possible options.

Comment: There simply is none. VIVO locks things down hard, and its target users are not tech-savvy enough to develop recovery and ROM for it.

Comment: [This claims to root](http://rootoreviews.com/root-vivo-V3-install-twrp-custom-recovery). I never owned Vivo brand so no hands on knowledge

Comment: Please specify by editing your question a) which are the apps you tried and failed. Otherwise, someone may suggest same app which didn't work. B) your current OS version

Comment: VIVO uses its customized os based on android

Comment: DId you try the instructions from here http://www.gogorapid.com/root-vivo-v3/ ? or here http://www.iroot.com/how-to-articles/how-to-root-vivo-x51-y13-and-other-phone.html ?

Comment: @esQmo , the first one I tried but failed and the second one doesn't listed my device (VIVO V3)